# nextjs an exported function is not a function when it's used in another file

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-context

I am learning NextJs and having an issue with using context.

Here is my context

```
"use client";

import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const UserAuthContext = createContext();

export function UserAuthWrapper({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ name: "test user" });

  return (
    <UserAuthContext.Provider value={[user, setUser]}>
      {children}
    </UserAuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useUserAuthContext() {
  return useContext(UserAuthContext);
}
```

However, when I use `useUserAuthContext` to retrieve user object, I get the following error

```
TypeError: (0 , _context_user_auth_context__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useUserAuthContext) is not a function or its return value is not iterable
    at Home (./src/app/page.js:14:93)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
```

Here is how the UserAuthWrapper applied in RootLayout file

```
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import { UserAuthWrapper } from "./context/user-auth.context";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <UserAuthWrapper>{children}</UserAuthWrapper>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Here is how I use the function

```
import { useUserAuthContext } from "./context/user-auth.context";

export default function Home() {
  const [user, setUser] = useUserAuthContext();
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <div>{user.name}</div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Update

============================

I did another test in my Home page

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { useUserAuthContext } from "./context/user-auth.context";

export default function Home() {
  const a = useUserAuthContext();
  console.log(a);

  const [user, setUser] = useUserAuthContext();
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <div>{user.name}</div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Then the error becomes

```
src\app\page.js (5:30) @ useUserAuthContext
 ⨯ TypeError: (0 , _context_user_auth_context__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useUserAuthContext) is not a function
    at Home (./src/app/page.js:14:93)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
digest: "1948578294"
  3 |
  4 | export default function Home() {
> 5 |   const a = useUserAuthContext();
    |                              ^
```

Here is my file/folder structure

[image]

Comment: _`return useContext(AppContext)`_... is it `AppContext` or `UserAuthContext`?

Comment: I'm not sure why it says "*is not a function*", the important part is "*its return value is not iterable*". Are you sure you're using `<UserAuthWrapper>` around `<Home>`?

Comment: Thank you @Phil. I have updated it but still get the same error.

Comment: @Bergi pretty silly error message. If it's not a function, it should just say so. If it is and the result isn't iterable, it should just say that.

Comment: @Ben you can avoid this particular error by providing a valid default context value... `createContext([{}, () => {}])`. Note that this won't solve you're actual issue which is that you aren't using the context consumer (aka `useUserAuthContext()`) within the context provider. It will make your context type-safe though

Comment: H @Bergi and @Phil, I update my question a bit with the layout file showing how UserAuthWrapper used. I also did another test to add another usage of useUserAuthContext. Then the error is changed to `is not a function`.

Comment: @Ben What does `console.log(typeof useUserAuthContext, useUserAuthContext)` print?

Comment: Hi @Bergi, it returns `object {}`

Comment: @Ben Hm, then something is wrong with your module imports. Are you sure you're importing the correct module? That your module resolution configuration is working? That you are not overwriting `useUserAuthContext` with something else later in the file?

Comment: Hi @Phil, folder structure screenshot has been added to my question.

Comment: The `page.js`  in `src/app` folder

Comment: I just realise, my `user-auth.context.js` is labelled as `use client`. When I add `user client` to the `page.js` file where Home page locates, it seems like works. But I did not see any instruction that both files should be in client side. I am quite new to server side rendering so a bit confused about the relationship.

Comment: @Ben I added the link in an edit so you might have missed it but see https://vercel.com/guides/react-context-state-management-nextjs

Comment: Thank you @Phil, I will read through it carefully.